# c# save datagridview to XML for later excel viewing

Tags: c#, .net, xml, data-binding, csv

i would like to save the contents of a datagridview to an xml file

i will then want to open the xml file using excel

perhaps i should be exporting it to CSV file instead of XML?

i dont care what method to use, i just need the simplest and fastest

i guess the process should be

1. copy the datagridview data into a datatable
2. save the datatable to a csv/xml

how would i accomplish this?

please note that i do not want to save the datasource of the datagridview (because i make changes to datagridview in runtime), i want to make sure to iterate through the datagridview and save the data that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set the DataGridView's Datasource as the datatable: [DataGridView.DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx)
2. Create a Datastream and export the Datatable using the built in Serialization: [DataTable.WriteXML(stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ctyc613.aspx)

I understand that you want the Datagridview table to export to a Datatable which then exports to a XML file. Consider that you can bind the Datatable to the Datagridview before Displaying your form. The Datatable will update along with your DataGridView as it acts a bindable source.

moreto follow

Comment: thank u perhaps u can help with this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139062/c-using-excel-to-open-xml-file

Comment: thank u very much for your help, is it possible to export to CSV instrad?

Comment: you will have to roll your own. there is an example found here: http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2007/01/exporting-datatable-to-csv-file-format.html If you need a full solution for a Datatable to CSV create another question.