# c# using excel to open xml file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, excel

how do i open an xml file using excel with c# winforms?

i am saving data to an XML file and i need the user to be able to see the file as soon as the application updates the xml file. i need the file to be opened with excel

Comment: Explain a little more? Is your application creating a separate process that starts excel?

Comment: My answer assues that you mean actually launching Excel. Is that what you want, or are you trying to load an Excel document from within your application?

Comment: Why not open the xml file with your C# winform?

Comment: @shiftbit, i am trying to open an XML file using excel as the viewer

Comment: What is your problem? Opening an XML file in Excel? Or getting Excel to be controlled by C#? And which Excel version are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Process.Start() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx). Using this you will be able to launch Excel, passing in the appropriate parameters to send it your XML file.

[Here's the command line switches for Excel.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/command-line-switches-for-excel-HA010158030.aspx)

Example:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\\program files\\microsoft office\\office12\\excel.exe", "/r \"c:\\My Folder\\book1.xlsx\"");
```

Comment: @GendoIkari thanks so much can u give me an example

Comment: @gend but i need to open an XML not XLS

Comment: Edited. Also check the examples given in the Start() documentation, especially here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx

Comment: @gend also isnt the excel folder different in everyone's computer

Comment: @I am - you can pass in any filename there, (any file that Excel can open). The example happens to use xlsx file, but you can pass in an XML file also.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Excel") //you do not need the full path. The Office Folder is an environmental path. Open CMD.EXE and type "echo %PATH%" to see default paths. If the user has MSOffice they will have the Office Folder as an environmental path. Gendolkari has given you the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Excel Interop library. Here is an example of creating a new Spreadsheet. Opening a file isn't much different. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28VS.80%29.aspx

If you only need to open the file, so the user can see it, use GendoIkari's method. If you need to interact with the file or read it, then use Interop.